# Unable to record mobile app steps using jmeter

Tags: mobile, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I tried the following in order to record mobile app steps using jmeter:

1. Start Jmeter on the my laptop and add the necessary recording templates.
2. Copied and installed the Jmeter cert on the mobile phone.
3. Connected the mobile phone to the same wifi that my laptop (with Jmeter) is on.
4. In the proxy hostname, I added the ip address of my laptop (with Jmeter). I also add the same port that was configured in Jmeter for my laptop.
5. Clicked start on the HTTP(S) Recording controller to start recording.

NB. I ensured my firewall was off during the recording.

I tried these steps several times, but when I use my mobile app on my phone, nothing gets recorded. I then tried navigating to a site using the browser but it does not record these actions either. Instead, it records other steps that I don't recognise. Please see links below for what I am seeing in Jmeter.

Does anyone have a solution to this?
[Recorded Steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGfK6.png)
[Errors Displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TATv.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error:

[image]

because JMeter is not capable of decrypting the intercepted traffic as you didn't install JMeter's [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) certificate onto your mobile device.

The certificate is called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and it's being generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).

I cannot provide exact steps for the certificate installation without knowing the operating system (including version) of your mobile device, however you might find the following material helpful:

- [Five Tips for Using Self Signed SSL Certificates with iOS](https://blog.httpwatch.com/2013/12/12/five-tips-for-using-self-signed-ssl-certificates-with-ios/)
- [Android: Add & remove certificates](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2844832?hl=en)
- [Recording Using Android Devices](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices-Recording-Using-Android-Devices)
- [Using self-signed SSL in Android (Nougat+)](https://medium.com/@johnmarktagle/using-self-signed-ssl-in-android-nougat-6d59593a3b6f)

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. I had actually installed the certificate on mobile device. But I still got the error.

Answer (score 0):

hey you have to "trust the jmeter certificate in your mobile device". in ios its "trusted certificates-->certificate trust setting--> enable button for jmeter certificate which you took from jmeter machine to the mobile (ios in my case)"